# Understanding queue arithmetic in data structures

Tags: data-structures, queue, circular-queue

When an element is inserted in a queue, `REAR = REAR + 1`. When an element is deleted from the queue, `FRONT = FRONT + 1` when queues are implemented using arrays.

Now, initially, both `FRONT = REAR = -1` indicating the queue is empty. When the first element is added, `FRONT = REAR = 0` (assuming array from 0 to n-1).

Now, if we assume a condition where `FRONT = 0 and REAR = n-1` implying the queue is full. When a few elements are removed the FRONT pointer changes. Let us say `FRONT = 5 and REAR = 10`. Hence, array locations 0 to 4 are free.

When I wish to add an element now, I add at the location 0 and `FRONT` points to it. But the locations 1, 2, 3 and 4 are free.

But, when the next time I try to insert an element, the code for the queueing arithmetic will throw an error saying the queue is full. Since `FRONT = 0 and REAR = n-1`. How do I insert at the remaining free locations and also understand this queuing arithmetic better?

I would also like to understand how `FRONT = REAR + 1` acts as a condition for checking if the queue is full?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to think circularly here in terms of relative, circular ranges instead of absolute, linear ones. So you don't want to get too hung up on the absolute indices/addresses of `FRONT` and `REAR`. They're relative to each other, and you can use modulo arithmetic to start getting back to the beginning of the array like Pac-Man when he goes off the side of the screen. It can be useful when you're drawing these things out to literally draw your array as a circle on your whiteboard.

*When I wish to add an element now, I add at the location 0 and FRONT points to it. But the locations 1, 2, 3 and 4 are free.*

I think in your statement above you got it backwards a bit. Insertions in a queue advance `REAR`, not `FRONT`. In such a case, `REAR` would be at 0, and `FRONT` would still be at 5. If you push again, `REAR` would be at 1 and you'd overwrite the first index, and `FRONT` would still be 5.

If `N=3` and `FRONT=2` and `REAR=2`, we have one element in the queue after pushing and popping a lot. When you push (enqueue), we set: `REAR=(REAR+1)%N` making `FRONT=2`, `REAR=0` giving us two elements. If we push again, `FRONT=2`, `REAR=1` giving us 3 elements, and the queue is full.

Visually:

```
     R
  [..x]
     F

   R
  [x.x]
     F

    R
  [xxx]
     F
```

... and now we're full. A queue is full if the next circular index from the `REAR` is the `FRONT`. In the case where `FRONT=2`, `REAR=1`, we can see that `(REAR+1)%N` is equal to `FRONT`, so it's full.

If we popped (dequeued) at this point at this point, we would set `FRONT=(FRONT+1)%N` and it would look like this:

```
    R
  [xx.]
   F
```

*I would also like to understand how FRONT = REAR + 1 acts as a condition for checking if the queue is full?*

This doesn't suffice when you use this kind of circular indexing. We need a slight augmentation: the queue is full when `FRONT` is equal to `(REAR+1)%N`. We need that modulo arithmetic to handle those "wrap around to the other side" cases.